# Where is op_inequality method? How to select it through hierarchy using .NET Reflector

Tags: c#, .net, .net-reflector

[image]I have an old dll of my application. I have to create new instructions in .NET REFLECTOR using Reflexil v1.7. 
The problem is where can i find op_Inequality method?
I have to write
OpCode=call
Operand=**System.Boolean System.String::op_Inequality(system.string system.string)**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how that should work in reflexil because I don't have an .Net Reflector installation.

What you're looking at is the [op_inequality](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) operator on the String class and that one looks like this:

```
public static bool operator !=(string a, string b)
{
return !string.Equals(a, b);
}
```

In c# the equivalent is

```
bool result = (a != b)
```

As you can see from the decompile instead of op_Inequality I expect you could drop in an virtualcall to `Equals` and then negate the branch.

```
IL_0024:  ldloc.0     // s
IL_0025:  ldloc.1     // v
IL_0026:  callvirt    System.String.Equals
IL_002D:  brtrue.s    IL_0038
```